# Listing after implementing ranking skipping numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to achieve ranking functionality as below:

```
 Name      Points      rank
 ram       9            1  
 kamal     9            1
 preet     8            2
 lucky     7            3
 kishan    6.5          4
 devansh   6            5
 neha      6            5
```

I have used below code to achieve this:

```
finalResult = finalResult.OrderByDescending(i => i.points).ThenBy(i => i.academy).ToList();
finalResult = finalResult.AsEnumerable() // Client-side from here on
    .Select((player, index) => new RankingEntity()
    {

        competitorid = player.competitorid,
        firstname = player.firstname,
        lastname = player.lastname,
        academy = player.academy,
        points = player.points,
        place = player.place,
        eventId = player.eventId,
        eventname = player.eventname,
        categoryname = player.categoryname,
        Rank = index + 1
    }).ToList();

var t = (from i in finalResult
         let rank = finalResult.First(x => x.points == i.points)
         select new
         {
             Col1 = i,
             Rank = rank.Rank
         }).ToList();

List<RankingEntity> ttt = new List<RankingEntity>();

foreach (var item in t)
{
    var a = item.Col1;
    var row = new RankingEntity();
    row.competitorid = a.competitorid;
    row.firstname = a.firstname;
    row.lastname = a.lastname;
    row.academy = a.academy;
    row.points = a.points;
    row.place = a.place;
    row.eventId = a.eventId;
    row.eventname = a.eventname;
    row.categoryname = a.categoryname;
    row.Rank = item.Rank;

    ttt.Add(row);
}
```

And i am getting result like below:

[image: Check this]

Please help what i am doing wrong.

Comment: ok, what is wrong? it seems rankings are correct.

Comment: if you check, the screenshot, after 16 it comes 19.. not 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is a ranking of a "group" so group the results by the points and then order the groups. For each item in the group give the same rank.

```
finalResult.GroupBy(item => item.Points) // Group by points
           .OrderDescendingBy(g => g.Key) // Order the groups
           .Select((g, index) => new { Data = g, GroupRank = index + 1}) // Rank each group
           .SelectMany(g => g.Data.Select(item => new RankingEntity
           {
               /* properties of each item */
               Rank = g.GroupIndex
           }); // Flatten groups and set for each item the group's ranking
```

The problem in your method is that you give the ranking for individual items and not the group. Then when you retrieve the rank for the group (`from i in finalResult let rank = finalResult.First(x => x.points == i.points)...`) you actually set for each item in the group the ranking of one of the elements in it. Therefore, if you first got the last item of the group - that will be the Rank value of each item in it.

---

Also notice that in the first line of your code you use `ToList`. Therefore there is not need to use `AsEnumerable` in the line under it - it is already a materialized in memory collection.